# onclick event is not working in chrome

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, google-chrome, onclick

I have problem with the `onclick` event in Chrome it's working in FireFox.

my code is:

```
<select type="list" name="adscity"  id="adscity" class="ads-select2" >
<?php while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)) { ?>
    <option value="<?php echo $row['id']; ?>" onclick="document.getElementById('adscity_h').value=this.value" >
    <?php echo $row['title']; ?> </option>
<?php } ?>
</select>
```

Comment: Your code contains unopened tags and braces, could you try copying a cleaner and readable version please?

Comment: I see no unopened tags or unopened braces but take a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9972280/onclick-on-option-tag-not-working-on-ie-and-chrome)

Comment: well, of course the `onclick` event works on chrome, but you need the `onchange` event... don't blame the tools, if the only tool is... well... you know what I mean

Comment: possible duplicate of [onclick="location.href='link.html'" does not load page in Safari](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6418634/onclick-location-href-link-html-does-not-load-page-in-safari)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this please. you should add 'onChange' event in `<select>` tag instead on onClick in `<option>`

```
<select onchange="document.getElementById('adscity_h').value=this.value">
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume that your option tags are in a select tag.

The jquery code:

```
$('#adscity').on('change', function(){
   $('#adscity_h').val($(this).val());
})
```