# creating href link within select option tag without the help of javascript or jquery

Tags: html, seo

I have dropdown and onchange of that dropdown I'm doing some ajax call and updating the table contens like this,

Main_page.php

```
<select>
    <option>go to one</option>
    <option>go to two</option>
    <option>go to three</option>
    <option>go to four</option>
</select>
<table>
    on change of dropdown will update this contents
</table>
```

also I have seprate link's
like,

http://example.com/Main_page.php/go-to-one

http://example.com/Main_page.php/go-to-two like this

now I want to give these http links to dropdown for **SEO purpose** and my problem is

```
<select>
    <option>
        <a href='http://example.com/pages.php/go-to-one'>go to one</a>
    </option>
</select>
```

This is not working (means `<a>` tag is not showing in the browser)

Here I can't put href by using javascript or jquery because I am doing this for SEO. Only possibility is I want to put using HTML only.

Can anyone help me to solve this?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Similar problem asked and resolved on here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6418634/onclick-location-href-link-html-does-not-load-page-in-safari

Comment: No, solving using javascript is easiest way, that I know already, But that's not SEO friendly right? I have clearly mentioned that I have to do this for SEO purpose.

Comment: And you show us a small fiddle for it. So that we can try to get you the html linking and also SEO links through JS or without it.

Comment: then you should use some DOM elements other than `<select>` and make them look like a drop down list.

Comment: Try using a Unordered list. And give it a look of select box using css. You will gain the SEO links and Select box look of it.

Comment: Really thank you Ejay and SSS. I got an idea I got some examples to do ul li dropdown. Thanks for your valuable comments.

Answer (score -1):

Try this. It worked for me.

```
<select>
    <option value='http://example.com/pages.php/go-to-one'>go to one</option>
</select>
```

Comment: How did you measure the effect this had on SEO so you could tell if it worked or not?