# Select input with redirecting on click without JavaScript

Tags: html, css

I want to create select input that will redirect an user on changing the option. I want to do that without any jQuery, is this possible? I remember using aria controls once, but I can't find any code, or any examples in the internet.

```
<select>
  <option value="1"><a href="all.php">All</a></option>
  <option value="2"><a href="doSomething1.php">Do something</a></option>
  <option value="3"><a href="doSomething2.php">Do something else</a></option>
</select>
```

How can I do that?

Comment: Not possible without `JS`/`jQuery`.

Comment: I'm 100% sure I was using aria inside HTML, might have been with jQuery, but I wasn't writing anything except for html.

Comment: Use `<select onChange="window.location.href=this.value">` It's the only way - to use JS. Therefore it's a duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12287672/links-in-select-dropdown-options

Comment: @KarolHernik you probably used Aria for accessibility and forgot that you had some JS involved.

Comment: Similar Question without answers here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23489931/creating-href-link-within-select-option-tag-without-the-help-of-javascript-or-jq