# Add an a tag using css or javascript

Tags: javascript, css

Is it possible to make an html tag a link to another page on website using either css or javascript?  I am trying to edit a wordpress site but it only gives options for custom css and javascipt.

Thanks

Comment: You are trying to programmatically add an anchor tag?

Comment: I do believe a simple Google search would assist you in seconds. It's best to provide what you have tried, so people will be more apt to help you.

Answer (score 2):

Try this javascript:

```js
document.getElementById("link").onclick = function() {
     window.location.href = "http://stackoverflow.com";
}
```

```html
<p id="link">Go to Stack Overflow</p>
```

and with CSS to make it look like an anchor tag:

```css
#link {
    color: blue;
    text-decoration: underline;
}
```

Comment: Is it possible to do it in css?

Comment: No, it isn't @AdamKatz CSS is only for styling

Comment: You can add text to a class with css though, I dont think it is unreasonable to think you could add an anchor tag...

Comment: Nope, not through CSS. Just not do-able @AdamKatz

Answer (score 1):

You can add html tags using javascript in a couple ways.
The most straightforward way (though it can be dangerous if you put malicious html in), is to use 
`someNode.innerHTML = <some markup>`, or if you have jquery: obj.html('');

Knowing that, you can use the html link tag (the `<a>`) to add a link.

so if I want to put in link to google in my header i'd first select my header:
`var header = document.getElementById('header');`

Then I'd add the a tag to the header:
`header.innerHTML += '<a href="www.google.com">Google</a>`;

Answer (score 0):

This is answered at [onclick="location.href='link.html'" does not load page in Safari](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6418634/onclick-location-href-link-html-does-not-load-page-in-safari).

`onclick="javascript:location.href='http://www.example.com/'"`