# Unable to identify a layered element in selenium

Tags: selenium, element, identification

I am new to selenium  and I have got this problem

## This is the code

```
<document>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<body>
<div id="wrapper">
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-static-top" style="margin-bottom: 0; background-color: #003e7e" role="navigation">
<div id="page-wrapper" style="min-height: 163px;">
<div id="content">
<div id="workArea">
<script type="text/javascript">     $(document).ready(function () {         $('.linkdisabled').click(function (e) {             e.preventDefault();         });     }); </script>
<div class="simpleForm">
<div>
<div class="row">
<div class="col-lg-12">
<h3 class="page-header">TimeSheet</h3>
<h3>
<span class="link_button btn btn-primary" onclick="location.href= '/TimeSheet/Create'">Click to Add Sheet</span>
</h3>
</div>
</div>
<div class="row show-grid">
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div id="footer"/>
</body>
</html>
</document>
```

================================

And I want to click on this

Click to Add Sheet

Have tired almost all that is there in selenium to identify and click it but it didnt worked... please help

Comment: Post the code that didn't work

Comment: Can't help without knowing what code you've tried

Answer (score 0):

Does it work manually? are you able to click on the text??
Reference -> [onclick="location.href='link.html'" does not load page in Safari](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6418634/onclick-location-href-link-html-does-not-load-page-in-safari)