# javascript code not working if placed at top of file

Tags: javascript, html

I have the following code. It set a filter bar in a search results page in a fixed position in the window after scrolling down to a certain point:

```
var docked;
var filters = document.getElementById('filters');
var init = filters.offsetTop;

function scrollTop() {
  return document.body.scrollTop || document.documentElement.scrollTop;
}

window.onscroll = function () {
  if (!docked && (init - scrollTop() < 0)) {
    filters.style.top = 0;
    filters.style.position = 'fixed'; 
    filters.className = 'docked'; 
    docked = true;
  } else if (docked && scrollTop() <= init) { 
    filters.style.position = 'absolute'; 
    filters.style.top = init + 'px';
    filters.className = filters.className.replace('docked', ''); 
    docked = false;  
  }
}
```

My issue is (and it's more curiosity) - if I place this code at the top of my file (in the `<head>`), it doesn't work at all. The filter section doesn't scroll with the window as it should. However, when I place this code at the bottom of the file (right above the closing `</body>` tag), it works just fine.

Why is this? Does this have something to do with the way the code works? Or could it be just a quirk or bug in the rest of my file causing this?

Comment: You have to wait till the DOM is loaded before executing this code.

Comment: [Script does not work when on <head>](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5853823/1493698)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Wrap your assignments in `window.onload = function(){ /* your code here */ };` and it will run. The reason being that your assignment of `var filters = document.getElementById('filters');` comes back as undefined since that element does not exist during page load at the time you reference it.

Example:

```
var docked;
var filters;
var init;
window.onload = function(){
 filters = document.getElementById('filters');
 init = filters.offsetTop;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

if you do this, it should work:

```
$(document).ready(window.onscroll = function () {
  if (!docked && (init - scrollTop() < 0)) {
    filters.style.top = 0;
    filters.style.position = 'fixed'; 
    filters.className = 'docked'; 
    docked = true;
  } else if (docked && scrollTop() <= init) { 
    filters.style.position = 'absolute'; 
    filters.style.top = init + 'px';
    filters.className = filters.className.replace('docked', ''); 
    docked = false;  
  }
}
);
```